# Need help creating index of slides with captions

Tags: javascript, html, css

To begin, I know this is a very basic question. However, I am not well taught in Javascript and I focus on design in general. On my website right now once you click on an arrow it takes you forwards or backwards within a collection of images. I would like for this function to also apply to the captions I created below the images. Once you click the arrow to move through the images, it should move through the captions below simultaneously. I almost achieved this by creating another function for the captions that would fire on click for the same arrows, this however, did not work. I would appreciate some help. Below is a bit of the javascript. I will also link the live website. Note that within the code is an index for dots which displayed the location among the slides, I however abandoned this idea.

```
var sliderIndex = 1;
function setSlider(){
showSliders(sliderIndex);
}
//slider image index
function plusSlider(n) {
showSliders(sliderIndex += n);
}

//dot index
function currentSlider(n) {
showSliders(sliderIndex = n);
}

function showSliders(n) {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("manualslider");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
if (n > slides.length) {sliderIndex = 1}
if (n < 1) {sliderIndex = slides.length}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) { 
  slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
slides[sliderIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
dots[sliderIndex-1].className += " active";
}

//Manual Slide
setSlider();
```

[Website](https://wallachportfolio.web.app/)

Thank you and sorry if this is basic.

Edit: the class name for the captions is manualsliderb

Comment: Greetings. It would be easier for us to understand if you provide more information, such as: 1) A working example of your code(HTML, CSS, JS), if possible wrapped in a code snippet, 2) Any solutions that you tried until now, 3) Screenshots or references that can help the community to understand and visualize your problem/goal.

Comment: Hi, I inserted a link to the website at the bottom of this post. I also talked about my attempted solution of creating a new function. I hope this is enough.